# How these earned badges are possible?

Tags: discussion, badges

[image]

Almost any silver or gold badge results in getting a bronze badge before it (in the middle of the way). For example, a question with 20 up-votes get the **nice question** silver badge, which means that when it's got to 10 up-votes, it's given the **good question** bronze badge.

Why this person (the image) in spite of having 92 silver badge and 13 gold badge, only has 21 bronze badge? Is this a bug? What is the explanation behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking at Pierre 303?

If I look at one of Pierre's posts, I see the following which seems to match your partial image:

[image: badge counts overflow]

It looks like there's too much text on that line that it is getting pushed out of view.

However, if I look at the [users page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) then the full count is visible, 212 not 21.

[image: oh hey 212 not 21]

Answer (score 2):

Pierre 303 actually has *212* bronze badges, not 21.

But there are actually several badges that do not have bronze equivalents:

- [Archaeologist](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/92/archaeologist): Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months.
- [Beta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta): Actively participated in the private beta.
- [Enlightened](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/36/enlightened): First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
- [Enthusiast](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast): Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days.
- [Favorite Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/38/favorite-question): Question favorited by 25 users. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
- [Generalist](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/14/generalist): Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.
- [Guru](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/43/guru): Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
- [Sportsmanship](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/58/sportsmanship): Up voted 100 competing answers.
- [Tenacious](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/34/tenacious): Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

So it's technically possible to have more silver than copper, and in certain cases—namely when you have a lot of first accepted answers or when your questions are favorited a lot—it's possible for silver to outpace copper, but that's pretty rare (so rare I've never seen it happen).